# Bootstrap 4 select styling

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-select

In my Bootstrap v4 forms I increased the padding of my `form-control` elements but I noticed that this padding isn't being applied to the `select` element.

```css
.form-control {
  padding: .6rem .8rem !important;
  border: 2px solid #ced4da !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputState">State</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option>...</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't build a custom version of Bootstrap so I have to override the behaviour by applying pure css.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oon0pmup/) that demonstrates the problem.

How can I correctly apply my padding to the `select` element in a Bootstrap v4 form?

Comment: height of the select element is currently set as `calc(2.25rem + 2px); }` - overwrite that with auto, if you want the un-opened select element to be the same size as the other input fields. (If you want the options to have padding as well, when the select field is opened - then you’re rather out of luck, because browsers won’t let you apply much formatting to those.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying to apply padding to Bootstrap 4 `form-control` elements is incorrect. Because Bootstrap 4 has native classes specifically designed to satisfy all your spacing needs. And also because applying css hacks like that can (and often does) lead to problems that require even more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks.

So, use `p-*` and `m-*` classes to apply spacing to your elements and avoid unnecessary hacks.

More info about Bootstrap 4 spacing utilities:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

### EDIT:

To fix your issue with custom css, you'll need to add the following rules:

```html
select.form-control{
    height: auto !important;
    padding: .6rem .8rem calc(.6rem + 1px) .8rem !important;
}
```

Here's the full, working snippet (click "run code snippet" and expand to full screen to compare side to side):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
.form-control {
    padding: .6rem .8rem !important;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
select.form-control{
    height: auto !important;
    padding: .6rem .8rem calc(.6rem + 1px) .8rem !important;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputState">State</label>
                        <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            <option>...</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Test</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Choose... (normal input for comparison)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT 2:

An even better solution would be to use a `.custom-select` because the normal select is inherently buggy. The `custom-select` was specifically designed for easy styling because the normal select is so buggy (and there isn't much that can be done about it).

Here's a code snippet with custom-select for comparison:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
.form-control {
    padding: .6rem .8rem !important;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
select.form-control{
    height: auto !important;
    padding: .6rem .8rem calc(.6rem + 1px) .8rem !important;
}
    
.custom-select {
    height: auto !important;
    padding: .6rem .8rem !important;
    border: 2px solid #ced4da !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputState">State</label>
                        <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            <option>...</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Test</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Choose... (normal input for comparison)">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputState">custom-select:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                                <option selected>Choose... (custom-select)</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Test</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Choose... (normal input for comparison)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `p-*` doesn't seem to have an effect on `select`. It also isn't accurate enough. I think these classes are meant for "layout" not "style".

Comment: @Luke Have you tried adding the `form-control-lg` class to your form elements? That might be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm after since it also increases the font size.

Comment: Check out the code snippet I just added. It fixes your issue.

Comment: Just added a second option that is even better than the first one.

Comment: Thank for that. Unfortunately, both your solutions still leave a discrepancy in height between the `input` and the `select`. I had to go with a hard coded `height: 2.95rem;` for it to work correctly.

Comment: If you check with an onscreen ruler, you'll see that there's absolutely no gap. What you are seeing as a discrepancy in height is actually an optical illusion in this case. I had double checked it with a pixel-perfect onscreen ruler and the height of the `custom-select` always matches the height of the input precisely! Pixel-perfect. However, I do agree that subjectively it appears to be different. (weird optical illusion)

Comment: You're correct. I missed your `custom-select` class. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Padding is being applied correctly, but you have to change the height

```
select.form-control{
  height:auto !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oon0pmup/3/

Comment: This seems to do something, but even with the naked eye I can see that the `select` isn't the same height as the `input`'s. This is going to be problem when a `select` is displayed next to an `input` as in the Form Row example given in the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row

Answer (score 1):

Use more specificity on the CSS selector to override the Bootstrap height:

```
select.form-control:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
    height: initial;
}
```

The select will be the same height as the text inputs (assuming equal padding, borders, etc.. are applied to all the inputs).

https://www.codeply.com/go/rJKOyAx1QA

Comment: Unfortunately, `height: initial;` does still leave a discrepancy in height between the `input` and the `select`.